# doing a show() does not let gui update until resize window

Tags: wpf

doing a show() does not let gui update until resize window.
I have a window that I hide for a while,(has to be over 30 min. or maybe after screensaver kicks in) then when I try to do a show and the gui pops up but it does not update. 
I am making correct updates to the gui, but they aren't seen until i physically resize the window. I'm thinking somehow the gui doesn't focus anymore. If I don't let it sit idle for a long time it never has a problem. Is there something I can do to force it to gain focus when I do the show()? thank you very much

Comment: Make sure your comments are long enough, you cannot post them otherwise. Do not edit answers like you tried to. Also, don't you know [how to accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) or did non of the answers you got so far answer the questions you asked?

Comment: Something's fishy. Are you calling Show from a STAThread, UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: You can also do a `Focus()` to make the window focus (in theory anyway).

But I don't think this is your problem.  Have you been able to reproduce this behavior on multiple computers?